# Building solutions in parallel with Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager

Tags: c#, microsoft.build

I'm trying to build multiple solutions in parallel across different threads and it isn't working.

The code looks like:

```
var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(new ProjectCollection())
{
    MaxNodeCount = 1,
    Loggers = loggers
};

var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(
    solutionFilePath,
    new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Configuration", "Release"} },
    "14.0",
    new[] { "Build" },
    null);

var result = new BuildManager().Build(buildParameters, buildRequest);
```

When executing this sequentially for each solution it works perfectly.  When this is executed simultaneously across multiple threads it fails with errors like:

```
'StartUp.cs', line: 10, column: 12, error: 'The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
'StartUp.cs', line: 10, column: 12, error: 'The type or namespace name 'OwinStartup' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
'Controllers\CacheController.cs', line: 2, column: 18, error: 'The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'
'Controllers\LogController.cs', line: 2, column: 18, error: 'The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'
'Controllers\LogController.cs', line: 3, column: 24, error: 'The type or namespace name 'Communication' does not exist in the namespace 'MyNamespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'
```

Initially this code used `BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager` which seems to be the most common useage however it is a singleton and this failed because a single instance of `BuildManager` can't only build 1 thing at a time. Creating a new instance of `BuildManager` gets past that problem but fails with the above errors.  I have tried setting the hostName parameter to a unique value for each thread or not providing it but this makes no difference (and I can find no documentation about what it means either).

Does this just have some static shared resources that prevent this from being possible or am I doing something wrong?  If there is any documentation that might help on this I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction (every search I've done on this just comes up with results for parallelizing project builds within a solution).